# Caddy throws duplicate site address with production.yml django cookie cutter

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, caddy, caddyfile

I'm using Django cookie cutter docker project trying to host on digital ocean. I tried to bring it up, It worked fine once, but later I made some changes to django code and had to restart it. So I stopped all the thins and fired up command again from themn onwards I'm getting this error

My Caddy env file:

> ## Caddy
>
> ## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> DOMAIN_NAME=balajidigitals.in

My production Caddyfile :

```
www.{$DOMAIN_NAME} {
    redir https://balajidigitals.in
}

{$DOMAIN_NAME} {
    proxy / django:5000 {
        header_upstream Host {host}
        header_upstream X-Real-IP {remote}
        header_upstream X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
    }
    log stdout
    errors stdout
    gzip
}
```

now when I run docker-compose -f production.yml up

Caddy throws the following error

```
caddy_1         | 2018/04/25 22:34:15 duplicate site address: balajidigitals.in
balaji_digitals_caddy_1 exited with code 1
```

what did I do wrong.

and one more doubt If I make changes to my django code Can I restart only django service instead of all the things. my questions may be stupid as I am very new to docker

Comment: Are you using this cookiecutter-django project? https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

Comment: can you post the full caddyfile